# Merge in snapshot vmdks in vmware workstation

Tags: vmware-workstation

Upon deleting all snapshots on a virtual machine, some delta vmdk's remained (`main-000001.vmdk`, etc.), with the vmware's harddisk pointing to those. How can I merge these deltas into the main vmdk file?

I've tried to use `vmware-vdiskmanager.exe` on the snapshot vmdk, but this only works on the first delta, on the second one it dies with:

```
VixDiskLib: Invalid configuration file parameter.  Failed to read configuration file.
Creating disk 'test.vmdk'
Failed to convert disk: One of the parameters supplied is invalid (0x100003e80).
```

I've tried to clone the virtual machine from the gui, but this shows `Cloning failed: One of the parameters supplied is invalid`.

I've run out of options, does anyone know of fixes to the above or alternatives to merging in snapshot deltas?

Comment: Does the VM still boot?  Are you sure your VMDK wasn't created with the option to split files at 4GB (which is the default)?

Comment: @Zoredache Fixed it in the end, but wasn't straightforward at all. See [my blog entry](http://simonscodes.blogspot.com.au/2014/10/consolidating-orphaned-vmware-snapshot.html).

Comment: @simonzack just wanted to let you know that we faced the exact same issue and your blog post helped to get it working, thanks for sharing!